# Custom Notification Depending on action

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, notifications

SWIFT 3 / Firebase
app like instagram/Facebook
Notifications

I am working on letting users know when another user e.g. liked their post, made a friend request etc.

I set up everything for cloud messaging with firebase and can send bulk messages at all my devices.

Now I want to introduce notifications which contain the current user, the user who did the action and what happened.

Unfortunately I did not find anything about this despite the general implementing of firebase cloud messaging.

My questions are:
1: Do i have to structure a database (e.g. .child("notifications").child(userId).... ?
2: How do I get the token from the stranger user I address with the notification?
3: How can I make the input variable?

I am happy about all kinds of help!

Comment: Here is a way to push notification for a specific user using Firebase Cloud Functions : https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

Comment: Do u know anything in swift? I am a beginner and have problems reading code which is not swift